# Set dynamic regions for each y axis group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I would like to implement an alternate region background to the chart, sort of like a striped table look.

Is there a way for me to dynamically set the regions for each y-axis block? Once I can do this, I can just basically use css to set alternating background colors.

Answer (score 0):

The regions can be set statically like this:
http://c3js.org/samples/region.html

To do it dynamically, you'd just need to use the API:
http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-regions e.g.

```
chart.regions([
  {axis: 'x', start: 5, class: 'regionX'},
  {axis: 'y', end: 50, class: 'regionY'}
]);
```

So to get alternating stripes build up a regions array as so after generating your `chart` object:

```
// find range of all data
var allData = d3.merge (chart.data().map(function(d) {
    return d.values.map (function(dd) { return dd.value; });
}));
var dataRange = d3.extent(allData);
dataRange.min = Math.min (dataRange[0], 0);
dataRange.extent = dataRange[1] - dataRange.min;

// set number of pairs of stripes
var stripeCount = 5;
var step = dataRange.extent / stripeCount;
var newRegions = [];
// then divide the data range neatly up into those pairs of stripes
d3.range(0,stripeCount).forEach (function(d) {
    newRegions.push ({axis: 'y', start: dataRange.min+(step*d), end: dataRange.min+(step*(d+0.5)), class: 'stripe1'});
    newRegions.push ({axis: 'y', start: dataRange.min+(step*(d+0.5)), end: dataRange.min+(step*(d+1)), class: 'stripe2'});
});

// set the new regions on the chart object
chart.regions(newRegions);
```

css:

```
.c3-region.stripe1 {
  fill: #f00; 
}

.c3-region.stripe2 {
  fill: #0f0;
}
```

(If, alternatively, you wanted to make a new stripe pair every 10 units on the y scale you would just make `step=10;` and change the d3.range to `d3.range(0,dataRange.extent/step)`)

I forked off someone's bar chart on jsfiddle and added the striping --> http://jsfiddle.net/k9c0peax/

Comment: This looks like a good start, but somehow the stripes are not lining up the y-axis perfectly. I'll see if I can play around and modify to get it right.